# Using the Pusher node.js library with callbacks causes an error

Tags: pusher

using the trigger function with a callback throws an error.  Am I missing something basic in this example?

This is the library

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-node

The error

Error: Invalid socket id: 'function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                done(err);
            }'
      at validateSocketId /node_modules/pusher/lib/pusher.js:24:11)
      at Pusher.trigger (/node_modules/pusher/lib/pusher.js:123:5)

My Code

```
      pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', {
            "message": "hello world"
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
            done(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for the Pusher Node Library `trigger` function is:

```
pusher.trigger(channelName, eventName, eventData, excludeSocketId, callback);
```

In the example in the question the `callback` is being passed where the `excludeSocketId` is expected. The code should be (notice the `null`):

```
pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', null, {
            "message": "hello world"
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
            done(err);
        });
```

Comment: Since the `excludeSocketId` is actually optional I'd prefer it to be an optional parameter. So if callback were passed as the 4th parameter the library should probably just type check `Function`. Maybe something for a pull request?

Comment: yeah sounds like a good idea- lemme see if I can carve out some time to do so.